# Adding existing user to existing group and providing permissions

Tags: ubuntu, user-management, ftp, user-permissions, usermod

can someone shed some light on this issue

I've set up and installed vsftpd. Created a user `ftp-user` and created a home directory, so they can log in, and just have access to drop their files here.

```
>> sudo useradd -d /home/ftp/ftp-user -m ftp-user
```

This works fine, user successfully logs in over ftp, uploads a file.

I now need to be able to access this ftp-user directory as another user say for example `ubuntu`. There is a script that runs as ubuntu, and I need to be able to access the directory to be able to grab the files and copy them across to other locations.

I tried to add `ubuntu` to the `ftp-user` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G ftp-user ubuntu
```

Although, when trying:

```
>> whoami
ubuntu
>> cd ftp-user/
>> -bash: cd ftp-user/: Permission denied
```

Hope someone has an idea - Cheers in advance!

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /home/ftp/`?

Comment: Ah - my permissions weren't allowing me in to the directory, I've updated this. Will try logging in and out. - Thanks!

Comment: note that `adduser ubuntu ftp-user` is an easier to remember way to add the user ubuntu to the ftp-user group

Answer (score 0):

New groups are only picked up when the user logs in. Log the ubuntu user out then in again.

Comment: running `groups` in a shell will list the current groups for that shell.